# PHP/MySQL - confusion about storing timestamps

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store a timestamp for form submissions in a PHP/MySQL form.  I would like to be able to query this field with the most flexibility for displaying the data in PHP.  What MySQL datatype is best practice, and which PHP function should I use to store/retrieve the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are unix timestamps the best way to store timestamps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178704/are-unix-timestamps-the-best-way-to-store-timestamps)

Answer (score 3):

I would store this data as `TIMESTAMP` data type provided by MySQL. This has lots of advantages over other storage options such as `DATETIME` or `INT` listed below

- It is especially meant to store a particular time instant. No matter which time zone your server is in, and which time zone your mysql client is in, the value of constant `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` stored in a `TIMESTAMP` field will always point to the same instant in the absolute time line.
- Internally it uses 4 bytes of space for storage, same as that of an `INT` data type
- It will give you pretty looking, human understandable values in regular queries.
- Moreover, these pretty looking values are converted to the timezone of the client connecting to it. This might be good or bad for you. You can always change it to a desired one, including UTC, with `set timezone='timezone'` if the mysql time zone table is populated or similar to `SET time_zone='+5:30'`. The latter would work only if there are no daylight saving adjustments in the desired timezone.
- Your queries can take the benefit of the fact that MySQL understands this field represents a date. So you could run query like: Get all the registrations happened on month of may for last 3 years.
- Use inbuilt functions to change the display format to show unix timestamp or any other valid form.

Comment: What's the "absolute time line" you're talking about?

Comment: Eventually we have to translate a representation of time into an event in the physical world. That is the absolute time line I am referring to here. An example would be say inauguration of London Olympics. No matter which time format (e.g. ISO8601, W3C), timezone (e.g. UTC, IST, PDT) you represent it in, it will always point to same instance of time.

The DATETIME data type doesn't have a timezone info attached with it making it mandatory for the client to get this information from other sources to point to a meaningful point on the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATETIME or DATE in your database: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

> What MySQL datatype is best practice, and which PHP function should I use to store/retrieve the data?

http://ch2.php.net/mysqli

Answer (score -1):

dunno what timestamp you're talking about but for the unix timestamp you'll need INT type field.