# How to compare dates of unknown format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

In My application I'm using four different types of date format :
**1. dd/MM/yyyy** .
**2. MM/dd/yyyy .**
**3. dd-MM-yyyy .**
**4. MM-dd-yyyy .**
based on chosen format user can retrieve formatted-date from date picker.Now I have to compare two dates,coming from two text boxes(date-picker) in screen.
I have tried allot but couldn't get proper solution for this bcoz of date-format.The following code is example for comparison :

```
var date1 = document.getElementById("<%=txt1date.ClientID%>");
var date2 = document.getElementById("<%=txt2date.ClientID%>");

if(date1.value > date2.value)
{        
    //do something
     return false;
 }
```

Now my problem is, how to get proper date in var so that this caparison can work for any of above format?

Comment: You could just use Moment, it's great

Comment: You're comparing DOM nodes, not dates btw

Comment: Might want to reconsider your approach—instead of using four different date format throughout your application, **settle on a single format** ([see guide here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178704/are-unix-timestamps-the-best-way-to-store-timestamps)). You can parse user input of dates to fit your selected format.

Comment: How does one know if it is the 2th June or the 6th of February?

Comment: @NinaScholz - Whats ambiguous about the 1st January (you could have chosen any other date to make the point - well it made me chuckle!)

Comment: The more the merrier, most users think it's fun when they can't understand how to input a simple date, you should add a bunch of cryptic error messages as well, that would go well with the overall theme.

Comment: @adeneo.. yes its DOM nodes here, thats what I'm using to retrieve date from textbox,so of-course it will come as a string...now what should I do to identify it as a date?Main problem is format, my app users are using different formats... as Ed Heal concern-how can JScript will understand which is month and date?

Comment: You're not getting it, `document.getElementById` gets an ***element*** from the DOM, a DOM node, it's not a string, it's an ***element***. If you wanted for instance the value of that element, you'd do `document.getElementById('myid').value` etc.

Comment: sry for that mistake...I have edited my qstn.. actualy I'm doing comparison by their value,as I edited now..

Comment: @SanjaySahu44—you can use a date picker with an unambiguous format (15-Feb-2016 works for me), or you can use a screen hint (not a placeholder) to say what the format is, then present it in an unambiguous format. Or have users choose the format they wish to use then you base parsing on the choice. How many ways do you want? BTW, you only have two formats: d-m-y and m-d-y, the separator is irrelevant, just split on a non–digit character.

Answer (score -2):

Use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var date1 = moment(document.getElementById("<%=txt1date.ClientID%>"));
var date2 = moment(document.getElementById("<%=txt2date.ClientID%>"));

if(date1 > date2)
{        
    //do something
     return false;
}
```

Comment: That's what I've been saying all along, one should always add an entire library to do some simple date parsing in javascript

Comment: This isn't even close to being correct. You are passing the entire DOM node to the `moment()` function.

Comment: And even if you pass the values rather than the elements, Moment.js will just guess at the format so completely unreliable.